# Change the position of the popup after flagging in the review tab

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, review, popups

When I use the flags tab on the review page and add my flag to a post, then the popup hides a part of the next post to review:

[image]

Before I am able to read the title of the next post I have to click on the popup to make it go away. The popup also disappears, when I click on another "flag or disagree ..." button.

It would be easier if I could read the next title immediately, without to click that popup all the time.

**Feature/Change request:** Please change the postion of that popup, so that it does not hide the next post. Then I could just ignore that popup and continue reviewing, e. g. like this:

[image]

Comment: I'd even say the popup is unnecessary here. Just show it when there's an error. If not, mark the post as reviewed and move on.

Comment: @slhck this would also be a possibility, I don't need a popup when everything is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design has been lately changed to:

[image: New design]

This fixes my issue.